# Какие Этапы создания email рассылки?

Tags: html, css, email, вёрстка-email, email-layout

Верстаю письма на фреймворке Foundation for emails. Но после верстки идут этапы тестирования и отправки. Огромная просьба написать порядок создания html писем, прямо по шагам, поделиться опытом, и какими сервисами тестирования и отправки пользуетесь (видел в сети - mailchimp, pechkin, litmus и т.д. Их настолько много, голова кругом). Нужен как всегда - ваш совет!

Comment: для корректных ответов, и чтобы вопрос не закрыли, рекомендую набросать свой примерный алгоритм этапов, а то вопрос слишком общим получается, и требует как бы решить за вас, а не помочь вам